# Regex to match domains with 3 dots

Tags: c++, regex, hostname

The regex purpose is to take a string and make a list of all hostnames, but only take the 3 dots from the right in it.

It works, but its possible to see that the script select the left of the hostname, not the right.

Regex

```
((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){1,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,63})
```

Now

**site.com** **1.site.com** **2.1.site.com** **3.2.1.site**.com **4.3.2.1**.site.com **5.4.3.2**.1.site.com

Fixed

**site.com** **1.site.com** **2.1.site.com** 3.**2.1.site.com** 4.3.**2.1.site.com** 5.4.3.**2.1.site.com**

Comment: you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[\w]`, or stricter `[:alnum:]`

Comment: For what i know \w has underline, so i think :alnum: being equal to "a-zA-Z0-9" is better.

Comment: Yes that's why I said if you need "stricter" condition use `:alnum:`, because otherwise in a URL you rarely find a `_`. `\w` is simply shorter. BTW why do you remove all the newlines? It's harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your regex for that, you need to limit the `+` with just `{0,3}` occurrences, and use a `\b` word boundary `(?!\.)` lookahead at the end to make sure we match the strings at the trailing word boundary and there should no be a dot after it:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){0,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,63}\b(?!\.)
                                                                ^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO2aH3/4)

Note that `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern and `{0,3}` *limiting* (bound) quantifier allows matching o to 3 occurrences only.

In C++, you may use a raw string literal (`R"(<PATTERN>)"`) to define the regex to avoid overescaping:

```
std::regex rx(R"((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){0,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,63}\b(?!\.))");
```

Comment: It works, but if the line has two hostnames it just match the right one.

Comment: But that is what your sample input suggests. What are the requirements then? Please add relevant test case(s) to the question.

Comment: Yes, the sample input suggests that, but it would be necessary for it to work with the whole text (or string), not only each line.

Comment: Try replacing [`$` with `(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/bO2aH3/3) (double the backslash in the C string literal if you are not using a raw string literal)

Comment: Replacing $ (?!\S) and {0,3} {1,3} (otherwise match words) works, but it doesnt match hostnames with a character at the end foo.co.uk/ gskinner.com,

Comment: Here you can see the problem regex101.com/r/sO4gW2/1

Comment: Ok, try [`(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){0,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,63}\b(?!\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/bO2aH3/4).

Comment: regex101.com/r/bO2aH3/5 restricted even more with TLD (will use all TLDs), but how can i make it match uppercase letters without repeating com|COM|net|NET|org|ORG

Comment: `[(com|net|org)]{2,63}` is not correct, it matches 2 to 63 single chars, either `(`, `c`, `o`, `m`, `|`, `n`, `e`, `t`, `r`, `g`. Try [`(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){0,3}(?:com|org|net)\b(?!\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/bO2aH3/6). To make the pattern case insensitive, compile the regex with a [`icase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/flags/) flag.